# Generating compile time functions string for formatting strings with libfmt

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, stdstring, fmt

I want to create a nice table in stdout. The table has a lot of headers that are mainly compiletime strings. For example:

```
std::cout << fmt::format("|{0:-^80}|\n", "File Information");
```

The above prints:

```
|-----------------------------File Information------------------------------|
```

I have lots of different type of fills and align widths. I decided to make some helper functions:

```
constexpr static
std::string_view
headerCenter(const std::string& text, const int width, const char fill) {

    // build fmt string
    const std::string_view format = "{:" + 'fill' + '^' + toascii(width) + '}';
    return fmt::format(format, text);    
}
```

I got this error while compiling:

```
Constexpr function never produces a constant expression
```

What is it that I am doing wrong, and how to do it correctly?

Comment: I doubt formatting could be done at compile-time. And if you use any run-time variables in the call to `headerCenter` call then it can't be compile-time either.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code `'fill'` is a multi-byte char.

Comment: You also have a problem that you add integer values to pointers. `"any string" + 'x'` doesn't create the string `"any stringx"`, it returns a pointer to `("any string")['x']`. Use e.g. `"any string"s + 'x'` to create a `std::string` for the string and append the character.

Comment: I recall compile time `std::string` is supported after C++ 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the format string and the return type of the function cannot be `string_view` since the format string is constructed dynamically, using `string_view` will result in a dangling pointer.

In addition, `fmt::format` requires that the format string must be a constant expression. Instead, you need to use `fmt::vformat`. This should work

```
static std::string
headerCenter(const std::string& text, const int width, const char fill) {
  // build fmt string
  std::string format = fmt::format("|{{0:{}^{}}}|", fill, width);
  return fmt::vformat(format, fmt::make_format_args(text));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4Tzb8GqaK)